# How do I enter a another zero without getting an error

Tags: java

```
Please Look at Images
```

When I run this it compiles but when the input message comes and I enter 864000000 it works and says 10,000 days. But if I add one more zero to 864000000(0) it gives me an error. Like error java.lang.parseInt(integer.java:583)
So mainly I just want to know how to add an  extra zero to this without getting an error and I want it to calculate into the message.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G6g7.png)

[The java file image][2]

http://pastebin.com/H8e8WAFx Here it is

Comment: Use a long, int's can't be bigger than `2147483647`.

Comment: There is no need to provide images, you can edit your question and paste all this as text. Please do so. Besides that you should have a look at this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html. It will tell you how big numbers are allowed to get for each datatype.

Comment: Because the number overflow `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Use `Long.parseLong`.

Comment: Check [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/IntegerMAXMINVALUE.htm) for upper and lower limit of `int`

Comment: If you had tried pasting your code in, you probably would have gotten related questions/answers displayed - since this is a duplicate

Comment: This is because, it is out from the range of the int data type, instead of int use long

Comment: I had to provide images since it wasnt letting me copy and paste it.I tried using Long.parseLong but that didnt work either.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/H8e8WAFx

Answer (score 0):

just add a cast

```
long value = (long) 9223372036854775807; //That's the maximum value for long (2^63-1) 
//The wrapper for long is Long so you can write Long.MAX_VALUE for the maximum value and Long.MIN_VALUE for minimum value
```

Answer (score 0):

The limit for the `int` type is 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647. 864000000 (first number) is less than the limit, but 8640000000 is bigger. If you want to be able to enter bigger values, you need to use the `long` type. This type has as a limit 2^63 - 1 = 18446744073709551616. `long` has the same properties as `int` and is used in the same way but can hold bigger values. If that is not big enough, you can use the `BigInteger` class in the `java.math` package. BigInteger is a class and its instances are objects so it's used in a different way. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) you can find more information about `BigInteger` if you are interested.